# Adding lists with values of strings and integers in Python

Tags: python, list

Is it possible to add two lists, with different value types in Python? Or is there an alternative way? For example:

```
listString = ['a','b','c','d']
listInt = [1,2,3,4]
```

I want to combine these so that the output string is either:
    `finalString = [('a',1),('b',2),('c',3),('d',4)]`
or
   `finalString = ['a',1,'b',2,'c',3,'d',4]`

Comment: Are you guaranteed the lists are the same length? If so, `finalString = [(listString[i],listInt[i]) for i in range(listString)]`

Comment: `list(zip(a, b))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip):

```
listString = ['a','b','c','d']
listInt = [1,2,3,4]

list(zip(listString, listInt))
# [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
```

And [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) or a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for the flattened version:

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain(*zip(listString, listInt)))
# ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'd', 4]

[x for pair in zip(listString, listInt) for x in pair]
# ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'd', 4]
```